# How to fix scuffs and scratches on wood door?

Tags: wood, varnishing

When passing a sofa through door I saw a few scratches after and even some irregularities.
[image]
[image]
[image]

I know there are some pastes I can use to fix the irregularities and on the past I used some kind of varnish with color on the door.

Is it the best alternative?

Answer (score 1):

I would go to a home store and look for a “scuff repair pencil” you need to replace the color first once you have it close then a light sanding and touch up varnish can hide these scrapes and scuffs. Next time you will know it is easier to pull 2 or possibly 3 hinge pins and not damage the door. Pulling hinge pins normally only takes a minute or 2 and the door is not damaged.

Comment: That seems a really good advice to always take the door out, about the scuff repair pencil I will search about it.